# Debug file size - Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In the below image, I have an XHR (request?) that is returning over 10mb. I tried to open this in a new tab, but Chrome runs out of memory and quits. How can I evaluate this file to understand what is making up the majority of the file size?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use something other than chrome to download the file.  You can right-click the entry and copy the URL then use something like wget to download the file.  There are also quick copy actions that will let you get full commands for cURL.